# How to open a https connection with httplib?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sms, sms-gateway

I wanted to do a script in python that sends a POST request to a service that sends multiple sms messages. the parameters I need to send are smsUSER, smsPASSWORD because at first I want to open a secure connection. It seems to be some problem with socket when I try to use the https connection.

Comment: HTTPS support is only available if the socket module was compiled with SSL support.  Is it?

Comment: solved it now. thank you.